# Wiring a light switched fan to a remote only fan

Tags: wiring

I am replacing an older pull chain fan that is also controlled with two light switches, One controls the lights and the the other the fan. The new fan I have has no pull chains and has a remote module in the mounting bracket. The old wiring coming out of the ceiling has a red wire, black wire, white wire and copper wire (ground). The new fan only has 3 wires. A black, a white and ground. How would I wire the new fan to work with only the remote control. The red wire is what is confusing me. How do I know if the black or red wire is the hot wire. I Assume it is the black but what does the red do? Can that one just be capped off and disregarded. Any input is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To have the fan work with the remote only, wire up the black to black, white to white and grounds. Cap the red wire. ( the black and the red are hot only with their respective switches in the "on" position.)

The fan will run only with remote input, HOWEVER, you need to be sure that the switch that controls the black wire remains "ON", or there will be no power to the fan.

You can also opt to remove the switch that powers the black wire and tie the 2 black wires from the switch together, making that black to the fan always hot.

You can remove the switch powering the red wire and cap them also., covering the boxes with blank plate covers.